# Normalizer of $GL_2 (\mathbb{Z}_p)$ in $GL_2(\mathbb{Q}_p)$

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

What is the normalizer of $GL_2 (\mathbb{Z}_p)$ in $GL_2(\mathbb{Q}_p)$?
the definition of the normalizer $N$ is  $\{g\in GL_2(\mathbb{Q}_p): g GL_2 (\mathbb{Z}_p) g^{-1} =GL_2 (\mathbb{Z}_p)  \}$. Trivially $N$ contains 
$GL_2 (\mathbb{Z}_p) 
\left(\left[
  \begin{array}{cc}
    1 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 \\
  \end{array}
\right]
 \mathbb{Q}_p^{\times}\right)$. Do they coincide?
How about for $GL_n(\mathbb{Z}_p)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $G=GL_2(\Bbb Q_p)$ and $ H=GL_2(\Bbb Z_p)$. If $g\in G$ normalises
$H$ then $ghg^{-1}\in H$ for all $h\in H$. But that implies $gh'g^{-1}\in H'$ for all $h'\in H'$ where $H'$ is the $\Bbb Z_p$-module generated by $H$. I'm pretty sure that $H'=M_2(\Bbb Z_p)$, so the question reduces to
which $g\in G$ have $gM_2(\Bbb Z_p)g^{-1}\subseteq M_2(\Bbb Z_p)$.

Multiplying $g$ by a scalar (as in your factor $\Bbb Q_p^\times$) lets
us consider non-singular $g\in M_2(\Bbb Z_p)$ and we can assume that
$p$ does not divide all entries of $g=\pmatrix{a&b\\c&d}$. For $h=\pmatrix{1&0\\0&0}$ then
$$ghg^{-1}=\frac1{\det g}\pmatrix{ad&-ab\\cd&-cb}$$
so that $ad/\det g\in\Bbb Z_p$ etc. Repeating this for the remaining
one-entry matrices gives a bunch of similar relations. I'm sure these are enough to prove that $\det g $ is a unit, but I don't have time to
look into the details right now...

Comment: From your equation, one  obtains $\frac{a^2}{ad-bc}, \frac{b^2}{ad-bc},\frac{ c^2}{ad-bc},\frac{ d^2}{ad-bc}$ are in $\mathbb{Z}_p$. By the assumption, at least one of $a, b, c, d$ is a unit. So, $ad-bc$ is unit also. Thanks a lot!